# Delphi: How to implement QueryInterface of IUnknown?

Tags: delphi, interface, iunknown, queryinterface

In Delphi, `IUnknown` is declared as:

```
function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
```

**Note:** The output parameter is untyped

In my `TInterfacedObject` descendant i need to handle `QueryInterface`, so i can return an object that supports the requested interface:

```
function TFoo.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
   if IsEqualGUID(IID, IFooBar) then
   begin
      Obj := (TFooBar.Create(Self) as IFooBar);
      Result := S_OK;
   end
   else
      Result := inherited QueryInterface(IID, {out}Obj);
end;
```

The problem comes on the line:

```
Obj := (TFooBar.Create(Self) as IFooBar);
```

Delphi complains:

> Operator not applicable to this operand type

Obviously i don't know how or what to assign to an **untyped** `out` parameter. i can randomly try things, in hopes that the compiler will stop complaining:

```
Obj := TFooBar.Create(Self);

Obj := Pointer(TFooBar.Create(Self));

Obj := Pointer(TFooBar.Create(Self) as IFooBar);
```

Ignoring all the code i've written (if required): how do i implement `QueryInterface` in an object descendant from `TInterfacedObject`?

---

The real problem i've been trying to solve can be boiled down to i want to:

> i want to override methods in an interface

In the same way:

```
TList = class(TObject)
...
   function GetItem(Index: Integer): Pointer; 
   procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: Pointer);
   property Items[Index: Integer]: Pointer read GetItem write SetItem;
end;
```

can be overridden in a descendant class:

```
TStudentList = class(TList)
...
   function GetItem(Index: Integer): TStudent; 
   procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TStudent);
   property Items[Index: Integer]: TStudent read GetItem write SetItem;
end;
```

i want to so the same with interfaces:

```
IFoo = interface(IUnknown)
...
   function GetItem(Index: Variant): Variant; 
   procedure SetItem(Index: Variant; Value: Variant);
   property Items[Index: Variant]: Variant read GetItem write SetItem;
end;

IFooGuidString = interface(IFoo)
...
   function GetItem(Index: TGUID): string ; 
   procedure SetItem(Index: TGUID; Value: string );
   property Items[Index: TGUID]: string read GetItem write SetItem;
end;
```

Problem is that how i have to begin loading up my implementing object with:

```
TFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo, IFooGuidString)
public
   function IFoo.GetItem = FooGetItem;
   procedure IFoo.SetItem = FooSetItem;
   function FooGetItem(Index: Variant): Variant; 
   procedure FooSetItem(Index: Variant; Value: Variant);

   function IFooGuidString.GetItem = FooGuidStringGetItem;
   procedure IFooGuidString.SetItem = FooGuidStringSetItem;
   function FooGuidStringGetItem(Index: TGUID): string ; 
   procedure FooGuidStringSetItem(Index: TGUID; Value: string );
end;
```

And there isn't just the two methods in `IFoo`, there's 6. And then if i want to add another supported interface:

```
IFooInt64String = interface(IFoo)
...
   function GetItem(Index: Int64): string ; 
   procedure SetItem(Index: Int64; Value: string );
   property Items[Index: Int64]: string read GetItem write SetItem;
end;


TFoo = class(TInterfacedObject, IFoo, IFooGuidString)
public
   function IFoo.GetItem = FooGetItem;
   procedure IFoo.SetItem = FooSetItem;
   function FooGetItem(Index: Variant): Variant; 
   procedure FooSetItem(Index: Variant; Value: Variant);

   function IFooGuidString.GetItem = FooGuidStringGetItem;
   procedure IFooGuidString.SetItem = FooGuidStringSetItem;
   function FooGuidStringGetItem(Index: TGUID): string ; 
   procedure FooGuidStringSetItem(Index: TGUID; Value: string );

   function IFooInt64String.GetItem = FooInt64StringGetItem;
   procedure IFooInt64String.SetItem = FooInt64StringSetItem;
   function FooInt64StringGetItem(Index: Int64): string ; 
   procedure FooInt64StringSetItem(Index: Int64; Value: string );
end;
```

And things get really unwieldy very fast.

Comment: I encourage you to post a question about your "real problem" as well. It sounds interesting, and I have a vague idea of how to do it (something about *aggregates* and *containers*). You might find that you're writing more code than you need to.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy If you can think of a useful title for it, that would generate interest, i'd definitely do it. i find that without a good *hook*, question goes unanswered. This question was good, because the question, as phrased, sounded easy - so i was sucking in people who thought they'd be able to give me an easy schooling. On the other hand, you and Uwe seem to patrol for Delphi questions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to type-cast the *left* side of the assignment statement. That way, the untyped parameter has a type, and the compiler knows how to assign it a value:

```
IFooBar(Obj) := TFooBar.Create(Self) as IFooBar;
```

---

Please note that you're breaking one of the [requirements of COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx). If you query for an interface, you should be able to query the result for IUnknown and always get the same value:

```
Foo.QueryInterface(IUnknown, I1);
I1.QueryInterface(IFooBar, B);
B.QueryInterface(IUnknown, I2);
Assert(I1 = I2);
```

If you just want to generate new objects of type TFooBar, then give your interface a method that generates those:

```
function TFoo.NewFooBar: IFooBar;
begin
  Result := TFooBar.Create(Self) as IFooBar;
end;
```

Comment: i can solve the one problem (always return the same `IUnknown`) by using the `implements` keyword, and delegate the new interface to an adapter class created in the property getter. But yes, that still causes the other problem of new objects each time. i would have to cache `n`-objects, one for each of the `n`-supported interfaces. *sigh*   Updated the original question with the actual problem i'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Besides of Rob's remarks of breaking the rules here, you can even succeed with this construct:

```
function TFoo.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
   if IsEqualGUID(IID, IFooBar) then
      Result := TFooBar.Create(Self).QueryInterface(IID, obj)
   else
      Result := inherited QueryInterface(IID, {out}Obj);
end;
```

I didn't investigate this, but you might get some problems with reference counting...

Comment: That certainly is a slick idea. But i think you're right, i would have to add a call to `_AddRef` somewhere in there.

Comment: I don't think you'll have reference-counting issues here. The reference count will be 1 while the constructor runs. When the constructor returns, the count goes to zero, but the object does not delete itself (see `TInterfacedObject.AfterConstruction`). Then the new object's `QueryInterface` method is called, and it sets the reference count for you.

Comment: The QueryInterface() call on the TFooBar object handles the needed _AddRef() for you.  QueryInterface() always increments the reference count of the interface it returns.

Comment: As I said, I didn't investigate. I knew there are wiser people around already knowing the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the implementation of TObject.GetInterface in System.pas I would suggest this:

```
  Pointer(Obj) := TFooBar.Create(Self);
```

Comment: You'll need to call `_AddRef` afterward. To call that, you'll need to type-cast `Obj` to an interface type. Better to just cast to an interface type in the first place, as in my answer.

Comment: You are right _AddRef is needed, I should have compiled and tried it before posting.